# SSRS Report Expression to display Weekly, Monthly and YTD totals

Tags: ssrs-2012

Have a report that displays daily counts and dollars. I'm trying to additional columns to display weekly, month to date and year to date totals.

In the past I've done this by creating separate weekly, monthly and ytd data sets and then used lookup expressions to populate the fields. Is it possible to use expressions that reference my primary data set, which includes a date column, to get weekly, mthly and ytd totals?

If this is possible, I'm not sure how to write the expressions to:
look back at the past 7 days and get totals for those days
Get totals for the current month 
Get YTD totals.

Any help that anyone can provide would be appreciated. I've attached an example of the report I'm trying to create.

Thank you.[image]

Comment: Can you post the SQL for the report?

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to use an expression for each as a filter your **Dollar Amt** column. It will determine whether to add the **dollar amt** or a 0 for each row of data.

I **ass**u**me** that you have a date field - I'll call it DATE.

**YTD**

```
=SUM(IIF(YEAR(FIELDS!DATE.VALUE) = TODAY.Year, FIELDS!DOLLAR_AMT.VALUE, CDEC(0)))
```

**Monthly**

```
=SUM(IIF(FORMAT(FIELDS!DATE.VALUE, "yyyyMM") = FORMAT(TODAY, "yyyyMM"), FIELDS!DOLLAR_AMT.VALUE, CDEC(0)))
```

The weekly would be a little different and depend on your week (sun - sat, mon - sun...) and your first day of the week setting but you get the general idea. If your using Monday - Sunday maybe something like:

**WTD**

```
=SUM(IIF(FIELDS!DATE.VALUE >= TODAY.AddDays(1 - TODAY.DayOfWeek), FIELDS!DOLLAR_AMT.VALUE, CDEC(0)))
```

The CDEC is used to add the 0 to the dollar amounts - otherwise you'll get an error when it tries to add 1.25 + 0. It's to **C**onvert to **DEC**imal.

The same logic will work for the counts - just use the Unit_Count field and remove the CDEC conversion for the zeroes.